# Python: Sockets not working over LAN

Tags: python, macos, sockets, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I recently came back from vacation, and my basic python 2 socket server is now unable to communicate with clients over LAN. The server is on a mac, and the client is my raspberry pi or my windows 7 machine. I have simplified the server and client code here to give an example:

**Server**

```
import socket
from thread import *

HOST = socket.gethostname()

print HOST

PORT = input ("Enter the PORT number (1 - 10,000)")



s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
print "Socket Created"


s.bind((HOST, PORT))

print "Socket Bind Complete"

s.listen(10)
print "Socket now listening"


    #Sending message to connected client
    #This only takes strings (words


while True:
    #Wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    connection, addr = s.accept()
    print "Connection Established!"

    connection.send("Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n")

    #loop so that function does not terminate and the thread does not end
    while True:

        #Receiving from client
        data = connection.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        connection.sendall(data)
        print data
    connection.close()
s.close()
```

**Client**

```
import socket #for sockets
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print "Socket Created"

#Get host and port info to connect
host = raw_input("HOST >>>   ")
port = 2468
s.connect((host, port))


while True:   
    #Send some data to the remote server
    message = raw_input(">>>  ")

    #set the whole string
    s.sendall(message)


    reply = s.recv(1024)
    print reply
```

**Question**

What is going on here? I am getting the local IP, but the scripts are still not able to communicate. Could it be an issue with the OS's?

---

**MORE INFO**

1. Pinging

   a. I was able to ping the PI from my Mac terminal:

   ```
   PING raspberrypi (67.63.55.3): 56 data bytes
   64 bytes from 67.63.55.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=240 time=17.434 ms
   64 bytes from 67.63.55.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=240 time=18.180 ms
   64 bytes from 67.63.55.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=240 time=22.046 ms
   64 bytes from 67.63.55.3: icmp_seq=3 ttl=240 time=25.124 ms
   64 bytes from 67.63.55.3: icmp_seq=4 ttl=240 time=31.773 ms
   ```

   b. My PI was not able to find the Mac as a host. I will see what I can do to remedy this.

   c. My PC was able to PING my mac. My Mac was able to ping my PC
2. Firewall

My Mac's Firewall is off. I will check on the [Raspberry Pi Stackexchange Site] to see if the PI has a firewall.

I will add more info once I test my windows machine

Comment: Can you ping the other machines? SSH them? Are their IP addresses static or dynamic?

Comment: @jozzas Not sure about IP's (I know that my external is dynamic) Pinging info was added.

Comment: Under Linux zuo maz be forbidden to bind to a port lower than 1024 if zou are not superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Running both scripts locally, they manage to connect and communicate on my machine. You are facing a networking problem, which should be easy to debug.

1. **Wrong Binding.**
   On the server, print the HOST you get. If the server has more than one IP you might try to bind on the wrong one. You can also change it to '0.0.0.0' (Just on the server side), and see if that works.
2. **Firewall.**
   Either side might be blocking tcp communication at the OS level. Debugging is done via [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) on Windows and [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) on unix. Start a sniff, run your code and see what went wrong. Most likely you will see the client send a `SYN` packet, but the server will fail to answer with a `SYN|ACK` packet. If you see the `SYN` packet reaches the server, try to shutdown the server's firewall completely and try again. If not, than the client is forbidden outgoing communication (less likely), and you will need to shutdown its firewall.
3. **In use port.**
   Try to remove SO_REUSEADDR for debugging and see if something changes.
4. **Exceptions.**
   Make sure you don't ignore any exception from your sockets.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried everything that you suggested and I am still having issues. My new info is above.

Comment: Can you post your tcpdump output?

Comment: Umm... What is that? I will find a way to do that... Do you need it for all of my computers

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine I've made some minor corrections though and explained them in comments inside the code:

**SERVER:**

```
import socket
from thread import *

# 1.Gets the local ip/ip over LAN.
HOST =socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) 

print HOST

# 2.Use port no. above 1800 so it does not interfere with ports already in use.
PORT =input ("Enter the PORT number (1 - 10,000)") 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
print "Socket Created"
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
print "Socket Bind Complete"
s.listen(10)
print "Socket now listening"
while True:
    connection, addr = s.accept()
    print "Connection Established!"
    connection.send("Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n")
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        connection.sendall(data)
        print data
        connection.close()
s.close()
```

**CLIENT:**

```
import socket 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print "Socket Created"
host = raw_input("HOST >>>   ")

# 3. Use the same port no. entered on server.py as the client binds to the 
#    same port
port = input ("Enter the PORT number (1 - 10,000)") 
s.connect((host, port))

while True:   
    message = raw_input(">>>  ")    
    s.sendall(message)
    reply = s.recv(1024)
    print reply
```

The above code just worked fine for me, I'm sure it would for u too as I've experienced the same trouble. The bugs found I've put them in the comments inside the code take a look.

Cheers ....!